# Javascript code not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am running this code and checking the log in firebug:

```
    var a = new Array();
var b = new Array();
for (i=0; i<2 ; i++){
    a.push(1);
    b.push(a);
    console.log("a", a);
    console.log("b", b);
};
```

The log shows these values:

```
a [1]
b [[1]]
a [1,1]
b [[1,1],[1,1]]
```

According to me the values should be:

```
a [1]
b [[1]]
a [1,1]
b [[1],[1,1]]
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I get the values that I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using `.push` to append `a` to the end of `b`, you're passing a reference and not *ByVal* as an *Array* is an *Object*. This means that future changes to `a` are reflected in the `a`s already in `b`.
What you need is to [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) `a` when `.push`ing to `b`.

```
var a = new Array(), b = new Array();
for (i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
    a.push(1);
    b.push(a.slice());
    console.log("a", a);
    console.log("b", b);
};
/*
a [1]
b [[1]]
a [1, 1]
b [[1], [1, 1]]
*/
```